# Can I also slide content with Fluid Powered TYPO3 (fed flux fluidcontent)

Tags: typo3, slide, fluid, flux, col

I try to slide content elements at my TYPO3 Backend (v6.2) with [Fluid Powered TYPO3](https://fluidtypo3.org/). So I don't have CSS_Styled_content included. http://wiki.typo3.org/Content_Slide Example:

```
10 < styles.content.getRight
10.slide = -1
```

Especially I'd like to slide my content from the `colPos=0 'Slider'` to the Pages below. Is this possible with FLUID / FluidTYPO3 (FLUX)?

```
  <f:section name="Configuration">

    <flux:form id="fluidpage" options="{icon: 'typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Resources/Public/Icons/Page/Standard.gif'}">
    </flux:form>

    <flux:grid>
          <flux:grid.row>
        <flux:grid.column colPos="0" name="Slider" colspan="2" />
      </flux:grid.row>

      <flux:grid.row>
        <flux:grid.column colPos="1" name="Left" />
        <flux:grid.column colPos="2" name="Right" />
      </flux:grid.row>

    </flux:grid>

  </f:section>
```

I try it like this ... but that's wrong.

```
styles.content.getSlider.slide = -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in just the same way it is done in `css_styled_content` internally, using a [CONTENT](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html) object:

```
lib.content_not_cascading_without_default = CONTENT
lib.content_not_cascading_without_default {
    table = tt_content

    # This enables content sliding. For more possible values
    # check the docs (linked above)
    slide = -1

    select {
        # Use the correct column position here
        andWhere = colPos = 1

        orderBy = sorting
        languageField = sys_language_uid
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you use fluid to render the template, you can also render the content using the [v:content.render](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Content/RenderViewHelper.html)-ViewHelper from EXT:vhs:

```
<v:content.render column="1" slide="-1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Jost! Perfect. I change it in my FLUID <v:content.render column="0" slide="-1"/> | wow, very easy!